# Is there a way to add multiple shapes in a fragment shader?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am a fairly new Threejs Developer and I wanted to see if there was a way to add multiple shapes in a fragment shader. For example in a threejs canvas, I can create multiple geometries all with different materials and stack them on a page. I want to try to replicate this just in a fragment shader. So in the shader have multiple rectangles all with their own gradients stacked on each other like I would do with geometries in a threejs canvas. To my knowledge this seems to go against the capabilities of a fragment shader but I am still curious if there is a way out there. Some way I can circumvent the threejs canvas in executing this.

Here is some code one can use to see what I am playing with.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

float rectShape(vec2 uv, vec2 scale) {
    scale = vec2(0.5) - scale * 0.5;
    vec2 shaper = vec2(step(scale.x, uv.x), step(scale.y, uv.y));
    shaper *= vec2(step(scale.x, 1.0-uv.x), step(scale.y, 1.0 - uv.y));
    return shaper.x * shaper.y;
}

vec4 firstColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); //red
vec4 middleColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0); // green
vec4 endColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0); // blue

    //vec2 rectPosition = vec2(uv.x, uv.y + 0.3);

void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.990,0.504,0.019); //orange
    vec3 bg = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0); //white
    float adjust = 0.5;
    vec4 col = mix(mix(firstColor, middleColor, uv.y/adjust), mix(middleColor, endColor, (uv.y - adjust)/(1.0 - adjust)), step(adjust, uv.y));
    
    float rectangle = rectShape(vec2(uv.x, uv.y + 0.3), vec2(0.25,0.6));
    color *= vec3(rectangle);
    
    float rectangleBG= rectShape(vec2(uv.x, uv.y), vec2(0.5,0.5));
    bg *= vec3(rectangleBG);
    
    vec3 combo = vec3(bg-color);

    gl_FragColor = vec4((rectangle)*col);
}
```

Comment: No there is no way.